# Attribute of a MultiDiGraph Edge

Tags: python, networkx

Please for a multiDiGraph in networkx with edge represented by the tuple in the list edge, how can I access or print out the attribute elements in the dictionary of attributes e.g. how can i print out length or type or lanes etc for a multiDiGraph

```
i = [(1001, 7005,{'length':0.35, 'modes':'cw', 'type':'99', 'lanes':9})]
```

The print statement below works for a Digraph but gives an error for the MultiDiGraph

```
print i, X[i[0]][i[1]]['length']
```

Thank you

Comment: This works for your specific example: `print i[0][2]['length']` but can you post how you are storing this in a NetworkX graph? You can access node attributes easily in NetworkX

Comment: @ EdChum This is an edge attribute not a node, read from an external file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you want then you can use `get_edge_data`:

```
In [35]:

import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(1001, 7005, length=0.35, modes='cw', type='99', lanes=9)
G.edges(data=True)
Out[35]:
[(1001, 7005, {'lanes': 9, 'length': 0.35, 'modes': 'cw', 'type': '99'})]

In [34]:

G.get_edge_data(1001, 7005)[0]['length']
Out[34]:
0.35
```