# How to access keys in nodes and edges in NetworkX MultiDiGraph

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

What I want to do is compare keys in nodes and edges. I have created a MultiDiGraph with the coordinates of the points I know as nodes, where the key is the `name` of the point with attributes listed below in my code. I have then created edges with `station_name` and `target_name` as references populated by data from the `observations` class I created elsewhere to store the data This way each edge can be either be outgoing or incoming rays. The data is read in from a file and stored in a series of classes based on the built in dictionary class in python, (2.7x), these classes have been treated as objects below, namely `knowncoords` and `observations` with `station` as a simple value holder class.

The NetworkX part of my code is set-up as follows:

```
def Execute(self):
 G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    #Adding known points as nodes to G
    for name, s in knowncoords.iteritems():
        #Below "Known":True because it is in the file, "OrientCorrn"
        #still has to be calculated for each station below, and I still
        #have to cycle through the points to check them hence "Checked"=False
        attr = {"Known":True,"Checked":False,"OrientCorr":0.0}
        G.add_node(name,attr)

     print G.nodes(data=True),"\n"   

     #print G.number_of_nodes()
     #print G.nodes(data=False)#Prints keys only
     #print G.nodes(data=True)#Prints keys with data as list
     #print G.node#Prints all nodes with key and data as embedded dict

    #Adds observations as edges based on station and targets
    for station_name,station in observations.iteritems():
            for target_name,target in station.iteritems():
                G.add_edge(station_name,target_name)
                G.edge[station_name][target_name] = {target_name:
                                                     (target.HA, 
                                                     target.VA, target.HD)}

                 #print G.get_edge_data(station_name,target_name)[0]
    print G.edges(data=True)
```

The output for the above is as follows:

```
[('WTOP', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False}), ('KB', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False}), ('TS8', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False}), ('STEP', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False}), ('WBOT', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False}), ('CNSTA', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False}), ('TS7', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False}), ('DP', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False}), ('FRNWD', {'Known': True, 'OrientCorr': 0.0, 'Checked': False})]

[('WTOP', 'TS7', (0.8767806941497847, None, None)), ('WTOP', 'STEP', (0.3830609857182666, None, None)), ('WTOP', 'N5', (2.2121078641665908, None, 62.281)), ('WTOP', 'TS8', (4.882321023750393, None, None)), ('TS8', 'WTOP', (1.098965956065474, None, 41.425)), ('TS8', 'N1', (2.6658692290010606, None, 116.121)), ('TS8', 'DP', (1.9014004722171114, None, None)), ('TS8', 'WBOT', (5.6203528905034394, None, 36.558)), ('N1', 'N2', (0.859046209694798, None, 271.342)), ('N1', 'DP', (0.6897638166617812, None, None)), ('N1', 'TS8', (4.640059627299959, None, 116.021)), ('N1', 'FRNWD', (6.1694140806336115, None, None)), ('N2', 'N1', (5.266419510746235, None, 271.418)), ('N2', 'N3', (1.0780607901360308, None, 166.267)), ('N2', 'CNSTA', (0.5640807179709452, None, None)), ('N2', 'FRNWD', (1.0797770305671586, None, None)), ('N2', 'DP', (1.9260968811328312, None, None)), ('N3', 'N2', (5.326260063405584, None, 166.258)), ('N3', 'N4', (5.86409296868126, None, 193.935)), ('N3', 'FRNWD', (2.1863642576996742, None, None)), ('N3', 'DP', (3.1192912242587547, None, None)), ('N4', 'N3', (5.294305993683654, None, 193.9380377)), ('N4', 'FRNWD', (4.789624647922251, None, None)), ('N4', 'DP', (5.645577746331569, None, None)), ('N4', 'N5', (3.048295108797074, None, 213.277)), ('N5', 'WTOP', (4.892555440558616, None, 62.282)), ('N5', 'N4', (2.384876067566785, None, 213.275)), ('N5', 'FRNWD', (1.2586829751701993, None, None)), ('N5', 'DP', (2.1078729227280406, None, None))]
```

What I would like to do now is compare the `name` key in nodes with the `target_name` key in the edges and if they are equal perform a calculation and update the `OrientCorrn` value in nodes. i.e. I am setup at WTOP observing to TS7 and I want to check if TS7 is in my nodes, if it is then I can perform some calculation based on that to update the "OrientCorr" value for the WTOP node.

I have tried `G.get_edge_data(station_name,target_name)[0]` but that doesn't return the `target_name` key I expected but rather the value of `target.HA` above, I can use the `G.nodes(data=False)` to get the keys for the nodes but how do I iterate through them? Or is there a way to check all edges against all nodes and just return the ones that match based my criteria such as:

`if (G.edge[station_name][target_name])==(G.node[name]):
     #do stuff`

Thanks in advance

Comment: does `G.get_edge_data(station_name,target_name)[0][target_name]` work? Also could you add the result of `G.edges(data=True)`

Comment: Nope, gave me a KeyError:
`print G.get_edge_data(station_name,target_name)[0][target_name]
KeyError: 0`

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output from `G.edges(data=True)` and `G.nodes(data=True)`

Comment: Will do but it really isn't the neatest... Will try and trim it down a bit from the full dataset

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655805/attribute-of-a-multidigraph-edge/22666701#22666701 so if I can see the structure of the attributes then I can suggest how to retrieve the data

Comment: @EdChum I added the output and a further explanation of what I'm trying to do below it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some sample data and code that reproduces this problem, at the moment I cannot reproduce your data accurately in order to answer it

Comment: I figure the easiest way to do that is just to let you download the entire thing:

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2yhD2zysFWZRVN3WjRSWS16Y1E/edit?usp=sharing)

Run the 'main' file, the networkx stuff is in the Window.py file, and the data is inside the Traverse\Data folder

Comment: Ah I solved it. My problem was my poor creation of my edges. I can't post my answer for another 8 hours though. I would not have figured it out if it wasn't for you pointing me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: I'm happy you managed to solve it, in the future it always helps to post the actual code and data to reproduce the problem, makes it easier for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was creating the edges badly, i.e. without a key for each attribute. I fixed it by changing the code below which creates an edge based on `station_name` and `target_name` but with a single key for all the attributes(`target_name`):

```py
G.add_edge(station_name,target_name)
            G.edge[station_name][target_name] = {target_name:(target.HA, 
                                                 target.VA, target.HD)}
```

To this:

```py
G.add_edge(station_name,
           target_name,
           target=target_name,
           HA=target.HA, 
           VA=target.VA, 
           HD=target.HD)
```

This let me call each edge based on `station_name` and `target_name` as before but now I can call a particular attribute based on a particular key for the edge in question. I then used the following loop to call the names I wanted (the ones which were in both the `observations` and `knowncoords` dictionaries I based the edges and nodes upon):

```py
for station_name, station in observations.iteritems():
     for target_name, target in station.iteritems():
         for name, s in knowncoords.iteritems():
             if (G.get_edge_data(station_name,target_name)[0]['target']) == name:
                print '@',station_name,'Target: ',
                         G.get_edge_data(station_name,target_name)[0]['target'], 
                         'which matches with', name, 'in knowncoords'
```

Which gave the output I wanted:

```py
@ WTOP Target:  TS7 which matches with TS7 in knowncoords
@ WTOP Target:  STEP which matches with STEP in knowncoords
@ WTOP Target:  TS8 which matches with TS8 in knowncoords
@ TS8 Target:  WTOP which matches with WTOP in knowncoords
@ TS8 Target:  WBOT which matches with WBOT in knowncoords
@ TS8 Target:  DP which matches with DP in knowncoords
@ N1 Target:  TS8 which matches with TS8 in knowncoords
@ N1 Target:  DP which matches with DP in knowncoords
@ N1 Target:  FRNWD which matches with FRNWD in knowncoords
@ N2 Target:  DP which matches with DP in knowncoords
@ N2 Target:  FRNWD which matches with FRNWD in knowncoords
@ N2 Target:  CNSTA which matches with CNSTA in knowncoords
@ N3 Target:  DP which matches with DP in knowncoords
@ N3 Target:  FRNWD which matches with FRNWD in knowncoords
@ N4 Target:  DP which matches with DP in knowncoords
@ N4 Target:  FRNWD which matches with FRNWD in knowncoords
@ N5 Target:  WTOP which matches with WTOP in knowncoords
@ N5 Target:  DP which matches with DP in knowncoords
@ N5 Target:  FRNWD which matches with FRNWD in knowncoords
```

All credit however goes to @EdChum for pointing me in the right direction!